# insert into error, using access db in c#

Tags: c#

ive got problem with my program, i got error in  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();, telling me "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

```
using (OleDbConnection myCons = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=QuizDatabase.accdb"))
              {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into HighScores ([ID],[Name],[Score]) values (?,?,?)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", score.Text);
                cmd.Connection = myCons;
                myCons.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                myCons.Close();

            }
```

thanks in advance! i really appreaciate fast response :)

thanks!! Steve for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AddWithValue is really handy, but could lead to errors. If any of your fields is of numeric type you need to convert to the appropriate type the value that you pass to AddWithValue. As it stands now your code passes all strings. Probably you need

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(id.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", Convert.ToInt32(score.Text));
```

By the way. If the ID column is an Autonumber column you should avoid to pass that value.

I concur with Jon Skeet about that it is better to avoid AddWithValue (and you should avoid it with Sql Server and other optimizing database engine). AddWithValue cannot accurately convert your input values to the underlying database type.

This is a very interesting article

[How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Comment: ohH! BTW!, i cant insert another one, it says it will replace the existing one, is there a method to insert data per line?

Comment: @MaryGraceIsananViaje: Well presumably you should be using a different ID for each record... were you trying to use the same ID twice?

Comment: 0w! i got it wrong, i just put wrong variable, thanks! problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", score.Text);
```

I would expect a score to be a *numeric* field, so something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Score", OleDbType.Integer).Value = numericScore;
```

... where `numericScore` is a variable of type `int` (or whatever's appropriate).

The same *might* be true for `Id` as well - we don't know what the field type is. Basically, you should try to make the *parameter* types match up with the *field* types as closely as possible. If you need to do any string conversion (e.g. parsing the value in a text box) I'd strongly recommend doing that in the .NET code rather than leaving it to the database.

(While you could still use `AddWithValue`, I believe it's a better idea to explicitly specify the type in the `Add` call and then set the value.)

Comment: i tried this

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Score", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(this.score.Text);

but still got the problem, but thanks for fast response!

Comment: @MaryGraceIsananViaje: Well what's the type of the ID column in the database? (Given that you've accepted the other answer, presumably ID is an integer. In future, when you ask a question please try to include all the relevant information to start with, so we don't have to guess.)